# Why am i getting false on HTTP Request method is "httpAuth.isRequestSuccess()" on status code 201 and status Created?

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, salesforce, httprequest, apex-code

[image]

Why am i Getting this "**httpAuth.isRequestSuccess()= false**" on **status code 201** and **status Created**?

Comment: What is `httpAuth`?

Comment: it's for authentication

Comment: OK :-) But I'm asking where you got it from, how it is created/constructed in the code, what "class" it is. I guess there's not many people answering here because what's in `httpAuth` containing the `isRequestSuccess()` might be non-standard? Is it from a framework, might it even be custom code? Could be just some guy programmed the `isRequestSuccess()`, in a way that it only returns true on a HTTP 200 OK? No way for me to look up or find out... searching on the Web for this function name brings up as the first hit/match this very post of yours here.

Comment: It's custom code and now problem is resolved now but thanks for the reply.